# HTML page elements gets imbalanced if the page gets resized

Tags: html, css

Following is my HTML & CSS code I written and works fine for horizontal view that is for a regular PC monitor, but I face problem when the page is resized to check how it will look in vertical format for mobile view.  Attached images of actual page window and how the elements look imbalanced when the page gets resized. How can I overcome this alignment problem?

### **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">  
    <center>
        <div style="width:30%; float:left; margin: 30px; ">
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="image" width="350" height="350">
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div style="width:60%; float:right; margin: 30px; text-align:justify; text-justify:inter-word;">
            <p><span style="font-size: 20px; line-height:150%;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum </span></p>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### **style.css**

```
#content {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 85%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color:rgba(255,229,194,1);
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

**Images**

Actual Page View
[image: Actual Page View]

Resized Page View
[image: Resized Page view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using widths based on percentages and pixels for margins.

(30px + 30px) * 2 + 30% + 60% becomes greater than 100% when 10% of screen width is less than than the sum of the margins (margins are doubled because they are left and right). This causes the second div to be pushed under the first.

Use percentages for margins too.

You have margins on both sides of two divs and 10% of screen width remaining, so change them to **2.5%**.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/LWZRZ/)

```
<div id="content">  
    <center>
        <div style="width:30%; float:left; margin: 2.5%; ">
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="image" width="350" height="350">
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div style="width:60%; float:right; margin: 2.5%; text-align:justify; text-justify:inter-word;">
            <p><span style="font-size: 20px; line-height:150%;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum </span></p>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks for solution Popnoodles :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/LWZRZ/2/)**

Just remove `margin: 30px;` from both `div's`. Instead use `margin` in %age if required.

Any thing in `px` will have two issues on resizing (or on smaller devices), either it will bring down near by `div's`, like in your case text is moving down or it will bring horizontal scroll on resizing (on smaller devices).

good luck!

Comment: Thanks Aamir for the explanation :)